# Not able to delete a row on click of delete button

Tags: javascript

I want to Add and delete a row on click of ADD button and Delete button. Add button is working properly but i am getting an "Object" error on click of delete button.

Thanks in advance.

Add row code:

```
function addRow(id){

        var table = document.getElementById("dataTab");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var idCnt=rowCount-2;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);


        var country = "country"+idCnt;
        var nmExch = "nameExchHouse"+idCnt;
        var inFlowFCinUSD = "inFlowFCinUSD"+idCnt;
        var inFlowFCinRupee = "inFlowFCinRupee"+idCnt;
        var outFlowFCinUSD = "outFlowFCinUSD"+idCnt;
        var outFlowFCinRupee = "outFlowFCinRupee"+idCnt;

        var element0 = document.createElement("input");
        element0.type = "checkbox";
        element0.name="chkin"+idCnt;
        element0.id="chkin"+idCnt;
        cell0.appendChild(element0);


        var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = (idCnt+1);


        var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("textarea");
        element2.name="nameExchHouse";
        element2.id=nmExch;
        element2.readOnly=true;
        element2.onblur=function (){getPreYearData(nmExch,idCnt);}
        element2.tabIndex=-1;

        var element20 = document.createElement("input");
        element20.type = "button";
        element20.name="branchbutton";
        element20.id="branchbutton";
        element20.onclick=function (){showNames(nmExch);}
        var element21 = document.createElement("br");
        cell2.appendChild(element2);
        cell2.appendChild(element21);
        cell2.appendChild(element20);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(3); <!--  Coutry -->
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.type = "text";
        element3.name="country";
        element3.id=country;
        element3.maxLength = "50";
        element3.className = 'toRight';
        cell3.appendChild(element3);

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(4); <!-- Inflow of foreign currency in USD -->
        var element4 = document.createElement("input");
        element4.type = "text";
        element4.name="inFlowFCinUSD";
        element4.id=inFlowFCinUSD;
        element4.maxLength = "15";
        element4.className = 'toRight';
        element4.onkeypress=function (){isValidAmount(event,this);}
        cell4.appendChild(element4);


        var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);  <!-- Inflow of foreign currency in Rupee equivalent-->
        var element5 = document.createElement("input");
        element5.type = "text";
        element5.name="inFlowFCinRupee";
        element5.id=inFlowFCinRupee;
        element5.maxLength = "15";
        element5.className = 'toRight';
        element5.onkeypress=function (){isValidAmount(event,this);}
        cell5.appendChild(element5);


        var cell6 = row.insertCell(6); <!-- Outflow of foreign currency in USD -->
        var element6 = document.createElement("input");
        element6.type = "text";
        element6.name="outFlowFCinUSD";
        element6.id=outFlowFCinUSD;
        element6.maxLength = "15";
        element6.className = 'toRight';
        element6.onkeypress=function (){isValidAmount(event,this);}
        cell6.appendChild(element6);


        var cell7 = row.insertCell(7);        <!-- Outflow of foreign currency in Rupee equivalent -->
        var element7 = document.createElement("input");
        element7.type = "text";
        element7.name="outFlowFCinRupee";
        element7.id=outFlowFCinRupee;
        element7.maxLength = "15";
        element7.className = 'toRight';
        element7.onkeypress=function (){isValidAmount(event,this);}
        cell7.appendChild(element7);
}
```

delete row code:

```
function DeleteRow(id){
     try {
             var table = document.getElementById("dataTab");
             var rowCount = table.rows.length;
             for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                 var row = table.rows[i];
                 var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                 if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                     table.deleteRow(i);
                     rowCount--;
                     i--;
                 }
             }
          }catch(e) {
              alert(e);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the error message?!

Comment: getting an "object error".

Comment: Will dig in, however at fist glance I would return an array of indexes to delete in one function. Another function that calls table.deleteRow for each element of the returned array. Also your condition can read && chkbox.checked

Comment: This code displays no errors for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/aaronfranco/x4zr49x5/

Comment: Where you are using the `id` parameter in `DeleteRow(id);`?